# I need help using the BEM method for my section

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bem

since i'm using nested div for product card, i'm having trouble using the BEM method when structuring my cards. For the rec__container, I am using display:flex so I can justify-content:space evenly. Then, for each card, I want to set a unique background image of the country name. Am I doing this correctly? If not, how can I fix?

```
<!----------Recommendations------------------------->
<section class="rec">
  <h2 class="rec__title">Recommendations</h2>

  <div class="rec__container">


    <div class="rec__card rec__card--hawaii">
      <h3 class="rec__title">Hawaii</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="rec__card rec__card--iceland">
       <h3 class="rec__title">Iceland</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="rec__card rec__card--greece">
       <h3 class="rec__title">Greece</h3>
    </div>

    
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's BEM by the book i.e. as it should be. Your BEM structure is readable i.e. self explanatory.

Each developer who's taking a look at your project, is able to immediately understand that all elements are tied to the **rec** block.

He/she can immediately understand that **card** is a repeating element of which several variations, expressed as modifiers (**hawaii**, **iceland**, **greece**), exist.

And most importantly: You are now able move your **rec** block anywhere in your project without ever having to fear that anything within the block is being changed due to a different location.

Well done!